# If I port scan a server on the outside of a firewall will this also tell me the ports the firewall is blocking?

Tags: firewalls, nmap

Theoretically I was thinking a firewall inspects the TCP header and looks at the destination port and discards/forwards based on its firewall rules.

So could I port scan an external server to the firewall and see what ports are returned?

I'm on a network where FTP, PPTP, and other stuff is blocked.  I just want to know what ports are open on the firewall and available to me.

Am I on the right track or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the external server answers on every port, which is quite unusual. But if that is the case you are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still having weird issues.  My port scan returns the open port on the server(22), I  can ping the server IP, yet the firewall is still blocking ssh connections.

Comment: Maybe some kind of content inspection. Try [Corkscew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) through the web proxy and run your SSH on 443. Has been working the last time I tried it in a corporate lan.